# How do I separate duplicated arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array and an integer:

```
ary = [2, 5, 4]
num = 6
```

If I define a new array called `this`, which is the same as `ary`:

```
this = ary
```

I added a number to `this`:

```
this << num
```

When I inspect the arrays, they are both the same:

```
p this
#=>[2, 5, 4, 6]
p ary
#=>[2, 5, 4, 6]
```

I only want to add a number to `this`, while `ary` should still be:

```
ary = [2, 5, 4]
```

Why does this happen and how can I prevent `ary` from also having the number added to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `ary` and `this` are references to the same instance of Array, the side effect of manipulating one will show up when you refer to the array using other variable.

If you don't want any side effects, use `ary.dup` to duplicate the array.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't actually create a new array.  You just made a second variable that refers to the same array.

To make a new array, you can use `dup`:

```
array2 = array.dup
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what's happening:

```
ary = []
ary.object_id # => 70207239648660
```

[`object_id`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id) returns an identifier for an object, in this case it's Ruby's ID for `ary`. That value will change every time the code is run, so don't expect it to match mine.

```
new_ary = ary
new_ary.object_id # => 70207239648660
```

You can see that Ruby says `new_ary` and `ary` are the same object.

```
ary << 1
ary # => [1]
new_ary # => [1]
```

If we change `ary`, both it and `new_ary` are changed as a result.

```
new_ary << 2
ary # => [1, 2]
new_ary # => [1, 2]
```

And vice-versa.

```
new_ary = ary.dup
new_ary.object_id # => 70207239645700
```

If we use `dup` Ruby copies the contents to another variable space and returns it.

```
new_ary << 3
ary # => [1, 2]
new_ary # => [1, 2, 3]
```

At this point `ary` and `new_ary` point to separate objects so changing one doesn't affect the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the deep_dup() method that returns a deep copy of the array.

```
ary = [2, 5, 4]
num = 6  
this = ary.deep_dup
this << num
```

And then check *ary* and *this* array:

```
p this
=>[2, 5, 4, 6]
p ary
=>[2, 5, 4]
```